# What does the FBI think about Bitcoin, in brief?

Tags: history, legal

Also related: [The context of FBI involvement with Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/the-context-of-fbi-involvement-with-bitcoin)

The [FBI document regarding Bitcoin](http://cryptome.org/2012/05/fbi-bitcoin.pdf) that [was leaked in May 2012](http://betabeat.com/2012/05/14/fbi-that-bitcoin-report-was-authentic-but-it-wasnt-leaked-by-us/) is very long. Is there a brief summary of the most important points somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most interesting part of the document isn't that long, as half of the pages explain some terminology and how Bitcoin works.

The main points made are:

- Bitcoin is the world's first decentralised currency, thus it is hard to audit and control it
- Bitcoins can become popular among criminals as they offer a lot of anonymity
- Bitcoins can be used to commit money laundering
- It is very likely that people wanting to steal Bitcoins will target third-party services (such as exchanges), and users' wallets
- It is hard to link user's identity to their Bitcoin address, but can be quite easy when they convert their Bitcoins into a fiat currency

There are also a couple other, smaller points made and it is generally a good read. As a side note, the paper appears to have a small mistake on page 4 - listing Bitcoin's lowest price since the bubble as 4$, whereas it was [as low as 2$ at some point](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/oct/18/bitcoin-value-crash-cryptocurrency).